# How can i set grid dataIndex at detail model in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs

I have two model and A has one B and one store.

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Column Demo',
    store: myStore,
    columns: [
        {text: 'b_id', dataIndex:'record_of_A.b().id' },  // such as this
    ],
    width: 400,
    forceFit: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a renderer:

for example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Column Demo',
    store: myStore,
    columns: [{
        text: 'b_id',
        renderer: function (value, meta, record) {
            return record.getb().get('id');
        }
    }],
    width: 400,
    forceFit: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johanhaest/HRFZK/

Comment: thank you! but i have some problem, I use this methods with rest proxy? the data property of record  is no other member except id.